# Execute package function by Mono Oracle client

Tags: c#, oracle, mono

I'm trying to call a package function by mono oracle client via this code:

```
        using (var connection = new OracleConnection(OracleConnectionString))
        {
            using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
            {
                command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                command.CommandText = "BIL.TRADE_OPERATIONS_PKG.GET_DOC_SALE_RETURN_SUM";

                command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("L_RESULT", OracleType.Int16)
                {
                    Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.ReturnValue
                });

                command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("I_DOC_SALE_ID", OracleType.Number)
                {
                    Value = 7021,
                    Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input
                });

                connection.Open();
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                viewBag.Count = command.Parameters["L_RESULT"].Value.ToString();
            }
        }
```

But it falls with following exception in OCIBindByNameBytes method:

System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalDirectiveException: 'Cannot marshal 'parameter #8': Invalid managed/unmanaged type combination (Int32/UInt32 must be paired with I4, U4, or Error).'

Any suggestion to solve this problem?
I tried to google it but didn't find any solution that worked to me.

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: We have wrapped all out functions in procedures. But this client has much more drawbacks that we expected (under the pressure it can return output parameters as null). So we decided to buy Devart driver, it works pretty good